# Making a Program to calculate a cellphone bill in Java

Tags: java, swing

I'm not sure why it isn't working, eclipse keeps telling me "A" "B" and "C" aren't defined as variables and keeps suggesting to make them defined ("A" "B" and "C" are all options the user can input to get a result). Could someone find a fix ?

```
/*
 * George Sayegh
 * Febuary 17th 2016
 * program for phone plan
 */

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Feb21716 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    double Package, Data, Bill;

        //Get Package
        String Packagetext = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your wireless service carrier plan" 
        + "\n Package A: For $29.99 per month 2GB of data is provided. Additional data is $10.00 per GB." 
        + "\n Package B: For $39.99 per month 4GB of data is provided. Additional data is $5.00 per GB. "
        + "\n Package C: For $49.99 per month unlimited data is provided."
        + "\n Please enter only the letter in Upper Case ex. Package A = A");
        Package = Double.parseDouble(Packagetext);

        //Get Amount of Data Used
        String Datatext = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the Amount of data you use in GB" 
        + "\n Please note, just enter the numbers "
        + "\n ex. 750 MB = .75  ");

        if(( Package == A )&&(Data <= 2)){
            // when Package is A and less than 2GB
            Bill = 29.99;
        } else if ((Package == A)&&(Data > 2)) {
            // when package is A and more than 2GB
            Bill = 29.99 + 10 * Data;
        } else if ((Package == B)&&(Data <= 4)) {
            // when package is B and less than 4GB
            Bill = 39.99;
        } else if ((Package == B)&&(Data > 4)){
            // when package is B and more than 4GB
            Bill = 29.99 + 10 * Data;
        } else if ((Package == C)&&(Data < 50)){
            // when package is C and less than 50gb
            Bill = 49.99;
        } else if ((Package == C)&&(Data > 50)){
            // when package is C and more than 50gb
            Bill = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have entered an invalid Number");
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your bill is: $" + Bill);



        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Start by using standard code conventions, such as starting variable names with lowercase. Then ask whether `double` is really the best data type for an alphabetic letter.

Comment: Why do you want the user to input a string and then convert that to a double? You could just read in the String (or character since it's only one letter) and compare that to 'A', 'B', or 'C'.

Comment: `double Package`? I strongly encourage you to follow naming conventions for Java. You are confusing yourself and others who read your codes.

Comment: I appreciate the help, got it working with the suggestions and pointers, double wasn't the best option as stated above and I will take into account the standard code conventions regarding the variables next project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/*
 * TMKRAY 
 * Febuary 18th 2016
 * program for phone plan corrected
 */
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Feb21716 {
   private static DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat(".##");
   public static void main(String[] args) {

double total;

System.out.println("Enter your wireless service carrier plan" 
+ "\n Package A: For $29.99 per month 2GB of data is provided. Additional data is $10.00 per GB." 
+ "\n Package B: For $39.99 per month 4GB of data is provided. Additional data is $5.00 per GB. "
+ "\n Package C: For $49.99 per month unlimited data is provided."
+ "\n Please enter only the letter in Upper Case ex. Package A = A");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String whichPackage = sc.nextLine();

System.out.println("Please enter the Amount of data you use in GB" 
+ "\n Please note, just enter the numbers "
+ "\n ex. 750 MB = .75  ");
Scanner dText = new Scanner(System.in);
double packageSize = dText.nextDouble();




if(( whichPackage .equals( "A" ))&&(packageSize <= 2)){
    // when Package is A and less than 2GB
    total = 29.99;
System.out.println("Your Bill is: " +df2.format(total));
} else if(( whichPackage .equals( "A" ))&&(packageSize > 2)) {
    // when package is A and more than 2GB
    total = 29.99 + 10 * (packageSize-2);  
System.out.println("Your Bill is: " + df2.format(total));
} else if(( whichPackage .equals( "B" ))&&(packageSize <= 4)) {
    // when package is B and less than 4GB
    total = 39.99; 
System.out.println("Your Bill is: " + df2.format(total));
} else if(( whichPackage .equals( "B" ))&&(packageSize > 4)){
    // when package is B and more than 4GB
    total = 29.99 + 10 * (packageSize-4);
System.out.println("Your Bill is: " + df2.format(total));
} else if(( whichPackage .equals( "C" ))&&(packageSize < 50)){
    // when package is C and less than 50gb
    total = 49.99;
System.out.println("Your Bill is: " + df2.format(total));
} else if(( whichPackage .equals( "C" ))&&(packageSize > 50)){
    // when package is C and more than 50gb
  total= 0;
System.out.println("You didnt enter a valid number "+total);
}



}
}
```

Comment: I quickly threw an example together using Scanners. I know this not the most efficient way but I only have a few minutes in between classes. I hope this helps. If you want me to convert it using JOption and Char later let me know I can do that later.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please add a little context to your answer. Introduce any code you post with an explaination. Like what did you do differently? Please read [these](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guidlines on how to write a good answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring Package a double, you can make it a char variable and Data and Bill could remain doubles. Because Package represents a single letter value (A,B,C), it would be better to store as a char. Doubles represent numerical values not letters.

So this is how it would look in the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   double data, bill;
   char packageVal;
   char package_A, package_B, package_C;

   //Get Package
   String packagetext = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your wireless service carrier plan" 
+ "\n Package A: For $29.99 per month 2GB of data is provided. Additional data is $10.00 per GB." 
+ "\n Package B: For $39.99 per month 4GB of data is provided. Additional data is $5.00 per GB. "
+ "\n Package C: For $49.99 per month unlimited data is provided."
+ "\n Please enter only the letter in Upper Case ex. Package A = A");
packageVal = Packagetext.charAt(0);

   //Get Amount of Data Used
   String datatext = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the Amount of data you use in GB" 
+ "\n Please note, just enter the numbers "
+ "\n ex. 750 MB = .75  ");

   data = Double.parseDouble(datatext);

   if(( packageVal == 'A' )&&(data <= 2)){
       // when Package is A and less than 2GB
       bill = 29.99;
   } else if ((packageVal == 'A')&&(data > 2)) {
       // when package is A and more than 2GB
       bill = 29.99 + 10 * Data;
   } else if ((packageVal == 'B')&&(data <= 4)) {
       // when package is B and less than 4GB
       bill = 39.99;
   } else if ((packageVal == 'B')&&(data > 4)){
       // when package is B and more than 4GB
       bill = 29.99 + 10 * Data;
   } else if ((packageVal == 'C')&&(data < 50)){
       // when package is C and less than 50gb
       bill = 49.99;
   } else if ((packageVal == 'C')&&(data > 50)){
       // when package is C and more than 50gb
       bill = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have entered an invalid Number");
   }

   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your bill is: $" + bill);
```

This should be enough to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your if statements you are comparing `Package` which is a `double` with `A,B` and `C` which are undeclared **variables** .

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog("your text here");
```

returns a String.

A better approach for you is to do something like the following.

```
String userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert package A,B or C");
```

and then inside your `if` statement use the `equals` method

```
    if(userInput.equals("A")) {
        // code to run if "A" is the userInput
    }
```

As a final note, try to follow proper code conventions as it will dramatically improve how readable your code is for yourself and others.